# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

Hello everyone i am trying to perform delete operation in my web app,when i am deleting an element from DB, in console its showing this error.Please give your valuable solution for this Thanks in advance.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
at _clearTreeSelection (orphanController.js:888)
at Scope.$scope.clearSelection (orphanController.js:659)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (orphanController.js:1058)
```

at line number 888 this is my code:

```
//This is to clear the selectedNode of angular tree on modal close
_clearTreeSelection = function () {
$scope.orphanData.orphanText = 
$scope.orphanData.orphan.attributes.text;//This is line no.888
if ($scope.OntologyTree && $scope.OntologyTree.currentNode) {
        $scope.OntologyTree.currentNode = null;
    }
};
```

at line number 659 this is my code:

```
$scope.clearSelection = function () {
    _clearTreeSelection();//line no.659
    _clearGazetteerSelection();
};
```

at line number 1058 this is my code:

```
_modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $scope.suggestionListSearchText = '';
        $scope.clearSelection();// line no. 1058
    });
}
```

I have checked all over stackoverflow, i cant find the suitable solution for this problem.

Comment: Debug your code & find out why `$scope.orphanData.orphan` is not getting data.

Comment: Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your `$scope.orphanData.orphan` is `undefined`. Find where have you declared this object and be sure that it refers to an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error since you are trying to access a property on a object but that object does not exist. You should first make sure that `orphan` property actually exists as an object so that you can access `attributes` property on it.

Changes you need to make:

```
$scope.orphanData.orphan = {'attributes': {}}
```